# How to make two matrices intersect with each other?

Tags: matlab

I have two cell matrices A and B, the size of which are both 10*1 cell matrix. 
For A, it looks like:`{A1;A2;A3;...A10}`. 
For B, it looks like:`{B1;B2;B3;...B10}`.

Ai and Bi are both 1*200 double vectors.

My question is how to make it looks like cell matrix C, the format of which is :`{A1;B1;A2;B2;A3;B3;...A9;B9;A10;B10}.`

Is there anybody can help me? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Why using cell arrays if your vectors are teh same size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-cell-arrays.html for details on how to combine cells.

An answer is:

```
C = [A,B]';
C = C(:);
```

Comment: Are you sure its correct? That would not give {A1; A2 ;A3...B1 ;B2; B3...} ?

Comment: Since A is 10x1 and B is 10x1, combining them like this gives me a cell array that is 10x2. The transpose action `'` results in a 2x10 cell matrix, then using the `(:)` converts it to a vector of 20x1, just like we want it.

Comment: Well, that is why this little transpose symbol is there.

Comment: @rayryeng I disagree, this is correct. This is the same as `[A'; B']` and when you call `(:)` it will intersperse the elements of `A` and `B`. I think this is a very elegant solution. But to be absolutely correct, you should use `.'` in case complex numbers are sneaking in somehow

Comment: @Dan - You're right.  I just did some tests.  Sorry Dan and JanDeGier.  +1 for you JanDeGier!

Comment: Yep same for me sorry about that!

Comment: @JandeGier - I misread the matrices.  I thought they were row cell arrays, not column cell arrays.  In that case, this answer is definitely right.  Good job!

Comment: @Dan - I misread the matrices.  I thought they were row cell arrays, not column cell arrays.  In that case, this answer is definitely right.